# How to restrict a menu item and its content to logged users in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

On WordPress, I'm setting up my online shop with WooCommerce plugin. I have a PHP script that generate a pricing table.

But actually everyone can see it.

How can I add it to my WordPress menu and no one could see it without being login in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script you will add `is_user_logged_in()` in an `IF` statement like:

```
function my_php_script_table(){
    if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        // The function code
    } else {
        return; // Exit
    }
}
```

Now in your Wordpress menu, you can add additional CSS classes enabling **"css Classes"** in the **"Screen options"** tab located up right of the "Menus" settings page.

[image]

Then once enabled, in your menu item you will be able to set a custom CSS class:

[image]

Then you will be able to hide from unlogged users this menu item using *(here the additional class is `hide_if_non_logged`)*:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'hide_if_non_logged_custom_inline_css', 500 );
function hide_if_non_logged_custom_inline_css() {
    if( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        ?><style>li.hide_if_non_logged { display: none !important;}</style><?php
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

You can even add redirection when user is not logged in for the page where the content that you want to hide from non logged users *(You will need to set the correct page slug or ID in the code)*:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'custom_unlogged_user_redirection' );
function custom_unlogged_user_redirection() {
    // Below set your correct page slug
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && is_page( 'pricing-table' ) ){
        // Redirect to logout URL
        wp_safe_redirect( get_home_url() );
        exit(); // Always exit
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.